# Prompt user for Google account authorization for mission critical features

Tags: permissions

I'm working on a webapp LMS that integrates with Google Classroom.

Some important features rely on this integration, which in turn can only work if the user grants my application the required [Google scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes).

I'm looking for the best way to get the user to grant my application the necessary scopes without too much hassle, while clearly communicating to them that such authorization is necessary for the app to work proprerly.

Here is some relevant information:

- the LMS is often used to deliver online and in-class quizzes/exams. Students may log in for the first time to take an exam and might not necessarily be familiar with the application flow
- in order to take an exam, students must first enroll in a course. Normally, students will enroll in a course during the semester to access material from the course and, on the day of the exam, they'll already be enrolled and ready to access the exam. When a student accesses an exam, they'll be shown a page like this before starting:

[image]

If they aren't enrolled yet, they'll first be shown this dialog so they can enroll on the fly

[image]

I want to absolutely minimize the friction on this "path" that leads the student to taking the exam, because even with a simple flow like this, we've observed several issues arise in practice.

Here's some things I thought of doing:

- when the user first signs into my application, I can request them to grant my application scopes. So when they select which account to log in with, they'll be presented this prompt:

[image]

- if a user doesn't select the necessary scopes, they'll be presented this banner while using the application:

[image]

Here are some issues with the above:

1. users might not (and likely will not) check the boxes of the scopes when logging in, because I can expect a tendency to just skip forward and click "continue" until the prompt goes away and the user is logged in
2. users might just ignore the banner and keep on with using the application without granting permission

It is very important that users grant scopes before taking an exam: that's requird for some important integration features to work. At the same time, I cannot stop the user from taking an exam if they don't grant scopes for several reasons, not the least of which a technical issue might prevent the user from successfully completing the auth flow, and I cannot deny them from taking an exam for that reason.

What could be a good way to handle this issue and get the users to grant scopes as soon as possible?

Comment: "I cannot deny them from taking an exam for that reason." Unfortunately, the upshot of that fact is that you run a high risk of primarily monitoring only the honest and conscienious users, while the dishonest ones will go unmonitored. It's as if the bank asked clients to turn on the security cameras when they walked in the door.

Comment: You make a good point. Let me rephrase that a bit: I don't feel comfortable denying access to an exam because of the nature of the event - people often do stupid things under pressure, to the point where students sometimes weren't able to find their university email account to log in. However, I may consider denying usage of the application outside of the context of taking an exam. Essentially, I'm looking for the best compromise between not being too intrusive and being assertive enough to make the user comply